# How to use variable in the select query PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, recursive, cursors, concat, variable

I'm looking for a way to write a recursive query, but I'm getting an error.
"SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "with recursive"
Position: 287"

query result "select * from tbl1" this is a list of numbers: 110,111,112...
Each number must be inserted into a row "s_table_sd_||r.cut_name||_db_tmp.e_pack_log"

i use:

```
with tbl1 as (
  select schema_name
        ,rtrim( ltrim( schema_name,'s_table_sd_'),'_db_tmp') as cut_name
  from information_schema.schemata s 
  where schema_name like '%db_tmp'
        and rtrim( ltrim( schema_name,'s_table_sd_'),'_db_tmp') <> ''
```

)

```
with recursive r as (
  select cut_name
  from tbl1
  union
  select * 
  FROM s_table_sd_||r.cut_name||_db_tmp.e_pack_log 
  where s_table_sd_||r.cut_name||_db_tmp.e_pack_log like '%'||r.cut_name||'%'
  )
  select * from r
```

Any ideas how to fix the request?

Comment: You need to put the `recursive` at the top with the _first_ CTE and you have to separate the CTEs with `,`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35249370/

Comment: `FROM s_table_sd_||r.cut_name||_db_tmp.e_pack_log` makes no sense to me. You cannot concatenate names of tables.

Comment: That does not look like a recursive query at all.